# Fourier series of non-periodic function $f(x)=e^{-\frac{ax}{L}}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, mathematical-modeling, periodic-functions

The definition of Fourier series states that

> It decomposes any periodic function or periodic signal into the weighted sum of a (possibly infinite) set of simple oscillating functions, namely sines and cosines (or, equivalently, complex exponentials)

I was a little confused as to how then, non-periodic functions like $f(x) = e^{\frac{-ax}{L}}$ defined over an interval $[0,L]$ can have a Fourier expansion ?
We know that
$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx) + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin(nx)$$

Note $\rightarrow$ $a,L$ are constants $>0$

What I fail to understand is, how is this possible for a non-periodic function like an exponential ? Somewhere on another question in MSE, I learned that The Fourier series is described for the periodic extension of a non-periodic function, which failed to clarify my doubts.

The motivation to ask this question comes from my attempts to solve

[Two fluids flowing perpendicular in thermal contact with a Wall [Help to mathematically model]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117489/two-fluids-flowing-perpendicular-in-thermal-contact-with-a-wall-help-to-mathema) and

[Evaluating Coefficients for a Fourier Series when Exponential terms are present [Approach needed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125729/evaluating-coefficients-for-a-fourier-series-when-exponential-terms-are-present)

Comment: What are the "standard coefficient finding formulae"?  The formula of which I am aware involves integrating over a single period of a periodic formula.  How do you define the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of a non-periodic function?

Comment: If you write down the formula for the Fourier coefficients of a non-periodic function, you get a representation of the Fourier series of its periodic extension (which is a discontinuous function even if the original function was continuous).

Comment: @Ian My recollection is that the *periodic extension* of a function refers to the extension of a function which is defined on a finite interval to a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.  For example, the function $$ f : (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\to\mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x $$ is non-periodic, but has a sawtoolh function as its periodic extension.  This is neither here nor there with respect to the question of a function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have added the relations I used to find the coefficients

Comment: @IndrasisMitra In those formulae, $L$ the the period of the function.  How are you choosing $L$ when $f$ is a non-periodic function defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes i will admit that I choose $L$ just because it is the region where I am trying to find the expansion. Can you elaborate a bit more on how then,I should go about with representing this as a Fourier expansion ? Or is it even possible ?

Comment: The usual idea is to take a Fourier transform, which can be thought of as a continuous analog of the Fourier series.  However, it might help to know **why** you want a Fourier "series" representation of this function.  This is beginning to smell like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @XanderHenderson You have guessd dexactly right. I am basically trying to find the Fourier coefficents at the last step of finding a Laplace equation solution where these terms crop up. You can check out this question which I posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125729/evaluating-coefficients-for-a-fourier-series-when-exponential-terms-are-present . Is there some way I could mitigate this term

Comment: @XanderHenderson For a complete description of the physical phenomena check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3117489/two-fluids-flowing-perpendicular-in-thermal-contact-with-a-wall-help-to-mathema

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90326/discussion-between-xander-henderson-and-indrasis-mitra).

Comment: @XanderHenderson The advantage of this perspective (that Fourier series really are defined on $\mathbb{R}$, with the coefficients being computed on a finite interval) is that it creates intuition for $L^2$ convergence rates and for pointwise behavior in the vicinity of discontinuities.

Comment: @Ian To be more specific can you provide some guiding points on how to find Fourier coefficients for this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125729/evaluating-coefficients-for-a-fourier-series-when-exponential-terms-are-present Some guiding points is all I need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to *Ian* and *Xander Henderson* for their suggestions.

We can consider any function defined on a finite interval $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ as a periodic function defined on $R$ by thinking that the function is extended to $R$ by repeating the values in $[a,b]$ to the remaining part of $R$.

Thus for $f(x)$ defined on $[a,b]$ where $(\frac{b-a}{2}) = l$, we have

$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg[ a_n \cos\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\bigg) + b_n \sin\bigg(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\bigg)\bigg]$$

where,

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{l} \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

$$a_n = \frac{1}{l} \int_a^b f(x)\cos\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x$$

$$b_n = \frac{1}{l} \int_a^b f(x)\sin\bigg(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x$$

Applying these for our function $f(x) = e^{-\frac{ax}{L}}$ defined on $x \in [0,L]$.

Hence, $a = 0$,$b = L$ and $l=\frac{L}{2}$, leads us to:

$$e^{\frac{-a x}{L}} = \frac{(1-e^{-a})}{a} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg[\frac{2a(1-e^{-a})}{(a)^2 + (2n\pi)^2}\cos\bigg(\frac{2n\pi x}{L}\bigg) + \frac{4n\pi(1-e^{-a})}{(a)^2 + (2n\pi)^2}\sin\bigg(\frac{2n\pi x}{L}\bigg)\bigg]$$